# How to sum hours with existing datetime in PHP?

Tags: php, datetime, time

I have two fields which store data like `2018-03-26 11:20:35` and `02:25:10`(2 hours 25 minutes and 10 seconds) first data is date and time. second one is only time. I want to sum it and finally my result should `2018-03-26 13:45:45`

How to do that in php code?

I have tried this way:

```
<?php
$date = '2018-03-26 11:20:35';
//echo $date;
//echo "<br>";
$hours = '02:25:10'; /* this data dynamic */
$sumTime = strtotime($date) + strtotime($hours);
$new_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $sumTime);
echo $new_time;
```

Output:

```
Warning: date() expects parameter 2 to be integer, float given in C:\my-project-path\test.php on line 7
```

Comment: Please Give a valid reason for downvote :(

Comment: What version of PHP gives that error? As lenient as PHP is with types, I don't know of a situation where it complains about a float instead of an int.

Comment: @deceze It'll happen on 32-bit systems, since adding two recent timestamps is higher than 2^31 and so gets converted to a float

Comment: Perhaps a good place to start for self diagnosis would be to print the output of each `strtotime` to see if the data is as expected (e.g. the appropriate UNIX timestamp). One of the values must be giving a float instead of an integer...

Answer (score 5):

Here's a simple solution, some checks are skipped:

```
// convert your date to DateTime object
$date = '2018-03-26 11:20:35';
$dt = new DateTime($date);

// convert your period to DateInterval
$hours = '02:25:10'; /* this data dynamic */
$parts = explode(':', $hours);
$interval = new DateInterval('PT' . (int)$parts[0] . 'H' . $parts[1] . 'M' . $parts[2] . 'S');

// Add interval to date
$dt->add($interval);
// Format date as you need
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 3):

You could create a duration in seconds by comparing today at `"00:00:00"` and today at `$hours`. Actually, `strtotime($hours)` returns the timestamp of today at `$hours`, so, the addition of the two timestamp don't give the expected result.

If `$hours` is lesser than 24 hours, you could use:

```
$date = '2018-03-26 11:20:35';
$hours = '02:25:10';

$d0 = strtotime(date('Y-m-d 00:00:00'));
$d1 = strtotime(date('Y-m-d ').$hours);

$sumTime = strtotime($date) + ($d1 - $d0);
$new_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $sumTime);
echo $new_time;
```

Outputs:

```
2018-03-26 13:45:45
```

Comment: If `$hours` (*duration, and not time of the day*) is more than 24, it will not work: https://eval.in/978681 .

Comment: @Glavić This is less than or equal to `23:59:59` Syscall Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Thank you @Glavić. I've updated the answer to specify that.

Comment: @Chinmay235: in your case yes; but this question will be here also for others, which could have time durations bigger than 24hours...

Answer (score 2):

It could be done with some simple string manipulation:

```php
$dt = new DateTime("$date UTC");
$modify = preg_replace('/:/', ' hours ', $hours, 1);
$modify = preg_replace('/:/', ' minutes ', $modify, 1);
$modify .= ' seconds';
$dt->modify($modify);
```

<kbd>**[demo](https://eval.in/978671)**</kbd>

If you have MySQL as your data storage, you could do:

```sql
DATE_ADD(field1, INTERVAL field2 HOUR_SECOND)
```

<kbd>**[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa1826/1)**</kbd>

Comment: I have used your query. Thanks you. :)

Answer (score 2):

You should check `DateTime::add`:

- http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.examples-arithmetic.php

Example:

```
<?php

// Convert h:m:s format to PThHmMsS format
sscanf('02:25:10', '%d:%d:%d', $hour, $minute, $second);
$intervalSpec = sprintf('PT%dH%dM%dS', $hour, $minute, $second);

$datetime = new DateTimeImmutable('2018-03-26 11:20:35');
$newDatetime = $datetime->add (new DateInterval($intervalSpec));
echo $newDatetime->format(DateTime::W3C);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like:

```
$hour = $hours->format('H'); //This way you get a string which contains the hours
$date->modify('+'.$hour.' hour'); //you modify your date adding the hours
```

I'm assuming you only need the hours, and not minutes and seconds

EDIT:

you can do like that using regexp

```
$date = new \DateTime('2018-03-26 11:20:35');
$hours ='02:25:10';
preg_match("/^([0-9].*):([0-9].*):([0-9].*)/",$hours,$matches);
$date->modify('+'.$matches[1].' hour');
$date->modify('+'.$matches[2].' minute');
echo $date->modify('+'.$matches[3].' second')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Why wouldn't OP need the minutes and seconds? It is in his/her desired output

Comment: Welp, that's what i understood at first read. But reading OP's post again i don't even now why i made this assumption..

Comment: `[0-9]` could be replaced with `\d`. Shorter and nicer :)

Comment: had sometime seen some preg_match issues where `\d` wouldn't work. That's why i put `[0-9]`. But yep you're right.